# How to get limit records with in Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following query 
I am getting id as a string

```
SELECT * from table_name 
where id in (1,2,3,4) 
order by created desc 
limit 0,4
```

this Query is giving me only 4 records

i want to get 4 records from each id

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT * from table_name where id = 1 order by created desc limit 4
    union all
    SELECT * from table_name where id = 2 order by created desc limit 4
    union all
    SELECT * from table_name where id = 3 order by created desc limit 4
    union all
    SELECT * from table_name where id = 4 order by created desc limit 4
) tmp
order by created desc
```

Comment: id is coming Dynamically as a string.

Comment: This should work. If you have a criteria to select the 4 items for each `ID` (like "the most recently created") put it in each inner query (e.g. `ORDER BY created DESC`). Otherwise each inner query will return 4 indeterminate rows (most probably sorted by the order they are on the storage device).

Comment: if my list of id is long, is it good idea to  write inner Query ?

Comment: If `ID` is coming dynamically then generate the query dynamically :-) Or just split it to values, use a prepared statement to run the query multiple times with different values of parameter `ID` then merge and sort the returned result sets in the client code.

Comment: i guess it's not good idea. if my id list is long , then it is not a good idea

Comment: id is field name . here. i am using in Clause